# How to replace list items with the corresponding value from a dictionary in this example? Using python

Tags: python

I have this list:

['79.9', '79.9', '79.9', '79.9', '103.2', '103.2']

I want to replace the list items with the corresponding value from this dictionary:

```
ValueDict = {
    "243": "0",
    "219.70000000000002": "1",
    "196.4": "2",
    "173.1": "3",
    "149.79999999999998": "4",
    "126.5": "5",
    "103.2": "6",
    "79.9": "7",
    "56.59999999999999": "8",
    "33.3": "9",
    "10": "10",
}
```

So the result will be a list like this:
[7, 7, 7, 7, 6, 6]

How can I do this?

Comment: What have you tried / researched already; and what issue are you experiencing?

Comment: Are you familiar with list comprehensions and looking up a value in a dictionary?

Comment: ```for i in range(len(list)): list_key = list[i] \n list[i] = ValueDict[list_key]```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
final_list = [ValueDict[i] for i in your_list if i in ValueDict]
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `enumerate` for adding a counter to the list, then check if the element is in dictionary, and call the value

```
for i,j in enumerate(l):
    if j in ValueDict:
        l[i]=ValueDict[j]
print(l)
```

Output:

```
['7', '7', '7', '7', '6', '6']
```

Answer (score 0):

something like the below

```
lst = ['79.9', '79.9', '79.9', '79.9', '103.2', '103.2']
ValueDict = {
    "243": "0",
    "219.70000000000002": "1",
    "196.4": "2",
    "173.1": "3",
    "149.79999999999998": "4",
    "126.5": "5",
    "103.2": "6",
    "79.9": "7",
    "56.59999999999999": "8",
    "33.3": "9",
    "10": "10",
}
new_lst = [ValueDict.get(x,'-1') for x in lst]
print(new_lst)
```

Comment: This can raise an error if the value is not in the dictionary

Comment: Depeding on the needs, it could be better than returning an incomplete resulting list.

Answer (score 0):

You could do it with [list comprehension](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_lists_comprehension.asp).

```
final_list = [ValueDict[value] for value in my_list]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
a = ['79.9', '79.9', '79.9', '79.9', '103.2', '103.2']
b = {
    "243": "0",
    "219.70000000000002": "1",
    "196.4": "2",
    "173.1": "3",
    "149.79999999999998": "4",
    "126.5": "5",
    "103.2": "6",
    "79.9": "7",
    "56.59999999999999": "8",
    "33.3": "9",
    "10": "10",
}
c = [b.get(i, i)for i in a]
c
['7', '7', '7', '7', '6', '6']
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
[int(ValueDict[x]) for x in list1]
```

[7, 7, 7, 7, 6, 6]

:)